# What is the past tense of the phrase "catch up with someone"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, past-tense

Can I use the phrase "caught up" to mean that I met someone after a long time?

e.g.

> I **caught up with** my friends on my way back to home.

Comment: That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Caught up" can have various uses (in all tenses, not just past)

**Yes, it can mean to see someone again** after a time of not seeing them, or even just communicating with them to see how they are doing, what is new with them, etc.

Similarly, you can catch up on, or be caught up on, **things such as news and current events**, tv shows, other media, etc.

Lastly, in a physical sense, you can **catch up to someone or something**, such as in a race you can catch up to the participant in front of you or anything else that may be in motion.